# PHP Session Data loses without http

Tags: php, session

I have a small issue with my php sessions - when I am logged in on `http://www.domain.com` it works, but when I remove the `http://www.` part I have to re-login again.

Is there anything I need to change in the php.ini so I can stay logged in wether the `http://www.` is there or not?

Comment: www behaves like sub domain so there is technically difference between `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`

Comment: I would use an .htaccess file to redirect your users to one domain or the other.

Answer (score 0):

That because your cookie is set on `www.domain.com` and after login you're trying to access it from `domain.com`. Browser will prevent it.

You have to declare cookie to be accessible for subdomains by setting `.domain.com` as 5. parameter of `setcookie()`.

Comment: I added session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com'); but sadly it didnt work. Is there a method to have the session running on the 2 urls?

Comment: @Codemunkie Did you set it before starting session?

Comment: yeah I did, at the top before session_start();

Comment: @Codemunkie Check if your session isn't started automaticaly (eg. in php.ini or by turning on errors reporting and checking if `session_start()` isn't printing notice.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to check the php ini variable : `session.cookie_domain`, it might be set such that it works only for full domain, try setting it with the sub domain only.

Comment: And check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244497/sessions-and-subdomains/5244838#5244838

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this (Probably not the best solution, but it does the job)

in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So it removes www. from the domain and redirects to http. :)

Thank you for all the help.